# How is 'reader mode' in Firefox triggered?

Tags: android, html, algorithm, firefox, user-experience

I'm using Firefox Mobile on an Android device and I'm fond of the ['Reader mode' features](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57529304-285/how-to-enable-reader-mode-in-firefox-for-android/). However, the feature is not always available (e.g. [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FullBashGuide)).
So I'm looking for information on the mechanism of this feature, because it's still unpredictable.

Does it look for some semantic, @ids/@class values or something else ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firefox on Android uses readability.js as the basis for its "Reader Mode" support. Here is a content guide for making pages that are easy to extract content:
http://www.readability.com/developers/guidelines

The original readability code used in Firefox comes from:
http://code.google.com/p/arc90labs-readability/

Note that not all pages can be converted into Reader Mode, in fact, that's not the intention. If you come across a page that you think should be handled by Reader Mode, please file an issue in the github issue tracker:

https://github.com/mozilla/readability/issues

Comment: The latest version of Firefox-on-Android's Readability.js script can be found [here](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/mobile/android/chrome/content/Readability.js).

Answer (score 3):

The developer of this features just [reply via Twitter](https://twitter.com/lucasratmundo/status/308620041551740928) :

> @edouard_lopez No docs, sorry. It finds for the main content of the
>   page based on a number of things (tag name, classes, id, etc).